# Python: how to build a dictionary of words from a list of files with words as keys and file names as values?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a list of words that I have extracted from several files, and I need to build a dictionary such that the word would be a key corresponding to a list of filenames in which the word appears (can be more than one) as its value.

I have already got code to extract all the words from the files and remove spaces, commas etc. So it is a list of words.

The output should look something like this:

```
{'on': ['file1.txt'], 'got': ['file1.txt'],'hello': ['file1.txt'],'a': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'], 'bad': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Loop over all the words of one file and for each word, add the filename to a list in the dictionary with the word as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this.

Note: This python script file must be located in the same location as the txt files.

```
files = os.listdir()
txt_files = []
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        txt_files.append(file)

words = dict()

for file in txt_files:
    with open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        word_list = file.readlines()
        words[str(file.name)] = word_list

print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

```
import os

wordLst = ['on', 'got','hello','a',
       'bad']

dic = {}

for word in wordLst:
    dic.update({word: []})

path = r'yourPath'
filelst = os.listdir(path)

for file in filelst:

if '.txt' not in file: continue

f = open(path + '\\' + file, 'r')
txt = f.readlines()

for key in dic.keys():
    if key in txt:
        dic[key].append(file)
```

Comment: btw, wordLst correpsonds to the list of words you have, so you have to replace this with your actual list. You also need to place at the path variable, the path of the directory in which there are the text files